# DataTable.js not adjusting column width Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, datatables

For some reason my [DataTable column width](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.width) is not adjusting.  I've copied from one page, which adjusted fine, to this page, but the column width is not working.

> The working page views/network_hosts/hosts_risk.html.erb:

```
<table id="device_table" class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Security Score </th>
      <th>Detected Name </th>
      <th>Nickname</th>
      <th>IP Address </th>
      <th>Mac Address </th>
      <th>Type</th>
      <th>Major Issues </th>
      <th>Minor Issues </th>
      <th><span class="nobr">Action</span></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <% @network_hosts_at_risk.each do |h| %>
    <tr style='color:#D7DBDD;'>
      <td> <%= h.status %></td>
      <td><%= h.hostname ? h.hostname : "Hostname Unknown" %></td>
      <td><%= h.nickname ? h.nickname : "" %></td>
      <td><%= h.ip_address ? h.ip_address : "None Detected" %></td>
      <td><%= h.mac_address ? h.mac_address : "None Detected" %></td>
      <td><%= h.os_vendor ? h.os_vendor : "Unknown" %></td>
      <td><%= get_host_issues(h, last_test, "major").count %></td>
      <td><%= get_host_issues(h, last_test, "minor").count %></td>
      <td>
          <a href='#'><i class='fa fa-close'></i></a>
          <a href='#'><i class='fa fa-eye'></i></a>
          <a href='#'><i class='fa fa-edit'></i></a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#device_table").DataTable( {
      order: [[ 0, "asc"]],
      pageLength: 50,
      dom: 'Bfrtip',
      buttons: ['copy','excel', 'pdf','csv','print'],
      columns: [ null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, { "width" : "10%" } ]
    });
  });
</script>
```

> The non-working page /views/network_hosts/index.html.erb:

```
<table id="device_table" class="table table-striped">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Security Score </th>
          <th>Detected Name </th>
          <th>Nickname</th>
          <th>IP Address </th>
          <th>Mac Address </th>
          <th>Type</th>
          <th>Major Issues </th>
          <th>Minor Issues </th>
          <th><span class="nobr">Action</span></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <% @network_hosts.each do |h| %>
        <tr style='color:#D7DBDD;'>
          <td> <%= h.status %></td>
          <td><%= h.hostname ? h.hostname : "Hostname Unknown" %></td>
          <td><%= h.nickname ? h.nickname : "" %></td>
          <td><%= h.ip_address ? h.ip_address : "None Detected" %></td>
          <td><%= h.mac_address ? h.mac_address : "None Detected" %></td>
          <td><%= h.os_vendor ? h.os_vendor : "Unknown" %></td>
          <td><%= get_host_issues(h, last_test, "major").count %></td>
          <td><%= get_host_issues(h, last_test, "minor").count %></td>
          <td>
              <a href='#'><i class='fa fa-close'></i></a>
              <a href='#'><i class='fa fa-eye'></i></a>
              <a href='#'><i class='fa fa-edit'></i></a>
          </td>
        </tr>
      <% end %>
      </tbody>
    </table>

    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#device_table").DataTable( {
          order: [[ 0, "asc"]],
          pageLength: 50,
          dom: 'Bfrtip',
          buttons: ['copy','excel', 'pdf','csv','print'],
          columns: [ null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, { "width" : "10%" } ]
        });
      });
    </script>
```

You'll notice the code is practically identical yet here is the difference between views:

> This one is right:
>   [image]
>
> This one is not adjusting:
>   [image]

What is going on here!?

Comment: what do you mean by "adjusting?" You mean the columns aren't adjusting automatically to account for the data or do you mean you can't manually size columns? Also, post the Datatables JavaScript.

Comment: @MarsAtomic the column rows were not adjusting their width, but as it turns out it was because of long column text.  I think I've fixed it with `truncate()`.